# Make a page reload and execute a script from the URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, search, refresh

This is what I've got so far:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("treeframe")[0].contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var idx = 0; idx < x.length; idx++){
    var link = x[idx].href;
    if ( link.indexOf("STRING_TO_SEARCH") != -1){
        alert("found!!!");
    } else {
        window.setTimeout("location.reload(true);",10000);
    }
}
```

The thing is that, after the reload when it is not found, it does not re-excecute the script.

Note: *the getElementsByName is needed because I need to search in a frame inside the page, but can not acces ONLY the iframe*

Comment: Where is this javascript?  Is it inline or on an onload event handler?

Comment: Like the title says, the script goes in the URL (or a bookmark).
*The webpage where i search is not mine.*

Answer (score 0):

So you're talking about a bookmarklet?  Or do you have this thing in a Frameset?  If its in a frameset, and you control the frameset then you should be able to attach an event listener to the  element that you are reloading.  Otherwise you can probably do some form of polling using either setTimeout or setInterval to check to see if the contents of the frame are accessible.

Comment: Bookmark, and I don't have controll over it. I tried making a html with an iFrame, but as it is not on the same domain, Chrome doesent excecute. I tried with a timeout, but when it refreshes, the clock goes away with the page and I can't keep it running after the first refresh.